# Power and work contradiction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, power, calculus

A body is starting from rest. A force is acting on it for a short period of time. In that given time, power delivered to it at any instance $t$ is given
$$P = F \cdot v_1 = ma \cdot v_1 = mv_1^2/t,$$
where $v_1$ is the velocity of the body at that instant. However,
$$P = \frac{\text{Work done}}{\text{time}} = \frac{\Delta (\text{Kinetic Energy})}{t} = \frac12 m (v_1^2-v_2^2),$$
where $v_2$ is the initial velocity. Since the body starts from rest, $v_2 = 0$. Thus,
$$P = \frac12 m v_1^2 \frac{1}{t} = \frac{mv_1^2}{2t},$$

*resulting in a contradiction*. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between average power and instantaneous power?

Comment: I am overriding the closure of this question as “homework-like.” I agree it is an *elementary* question, and there is probably a duplicate somewhere. It has the shape of an off-topic homework question if you only skim it, because the first sentence reads like a problem setup and the text before the question mark is “where have I gone wrong.” But the question here is not “what is the answer”; it is fundamentally “why are these two things different,” which is deeper and more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

You haven't been rigorous enough.

Newton's second law tells us:
$$F=ma$$
$$a=\frac{F}{m}$$
Because the force applied is constant we can write:
$$\Delta v=v_1-v_2=a\Delta t=\frac{F\Delta t}{m}$$
with:
$$v_2=0$$
Calculating the work from the change in Kinetic energy $K$:
$$W=\Delta K=\frac12 mv_1^2-\frac12 mv_2^2=\frac12 mv_1^2$$
$$P=\frac{1}{2\Delta t}mv_1^2$$
Again, because $F$ is constant:
$$W=F\Delta x$$
$$P=\frac{\Delta W}{\Delta t}=F\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=Fv_{av}$$

Here, *we need to use the average speed* $v_{av}$ because speed here varies (linearly) from $0$ to $v_1$, so:
$$P=F\frac{v_1}{2}$$
$$P=ma\frac{v_1}{2}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}\frac{v_1}{2}=\frac{v_1}{2\Delta t}mv_1=\frac{1}{2\Delta t}mv_1^2$$

**So we get the same result both ways.**

Answer (score 1):

The equation $P=Fv$ (or more precisely $P=\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf v$) gives you the **instantaneous** power supplied by the force $F$.

The equation $P=\Delta\text{KE}/\Delta t$ is the **average** power supplied by the force over the time interval $\Delta t$.

This is why your answers are off by a factor of $2$. You are calculating two different things. The question asks for the power at any time, so you want the instantaneous one.

Answer (score 0):

This goes like  this
$$P=\frac{dW}{dt}=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}=m\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{v}$$
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{v}=\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\cdot \mathbf{v}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}v^2$$
So that
$$\boxed{P=\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}mv^2\right)}$$
As required :)

Comment: Note that $$\frac{d}{dt}v^2=\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}+\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\cdot \mathbf{v}=2\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\cdot \mathbf{v}$$